# Flowplayer Provider specified in clip is not loaded

Tags: javascript, flash, flowplayer

What does "Provider specified in clip is not loaded, 202" error in flowplayer mean? Providers are HTTP or RTMP for streaming. So, does Provider not loaded mean a connection issue?

Comment: Please provide some configuration examples and the exact error message

Answer (score 2, accepted):

FlowPlayer error code 202 usually means that the plugin required to play the file has not been loaded. Some plugins will be detected automatically if they are placed in the same folder with the flowplayer SWF file, but others will need to be set in FlowPlayer configuration.

It sounds like you're using the RTMP plugin. Make sure you have the plugin in the right place, and then configure FlowPlayer to look for it. The documentation is here:
http://flash.flowplayer.org/plugins/streaming/rtmp.html

The FlowPlayer Error Codes are documented on this page:
http://flash.flowplayer.org/documentation/configuration/player.html

This page also gives some generic configuration examples.